# Semantic UI Multiple Modals works but previous modals are closed

Tags: jquery, pug, semantic-ui

Any help in solving this is greatly appreciated.

Semantic UI multiple modals are not working as expected, despite setting `allowMultiple: true`. In this example I have used 2 modals, a parent and child. I have used the example provided on semantic UI documentation https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#multiple-modals.

***Expected Result***
The parent modal should remain open when child modal is triggered

***Actual Result***
The parent modal is closed when child model is opened

***Codepen***
https://codepen.io/rbglyfe/pen/XWMowYY

***HTML (Pug)***

```
.ui.padded.one.column.grid
  .column
    .ui.basic.grey.button.modalBtn Click Me!
.ui.modal.parent
  i.close.icon
  .header Parent Modal
  .content Multiple modals allowed
  .actions
    .ui.approve.button Open Child
    .ui.deny.button Cancel
.ui.modal.child
  .header Child Modal
  .content Parent should remain open
  .actions
    .ui.approve.button OK
    .ui.deny.button Cancel
```

***JQuery***

```
$(function () {
  $(".modalBtn").on("click", function () {
    $(".ui.modal.parent").modal(
      {
        onShow: function () {
          alert("parent");
        }
      },
      { allowMultiple: true }
    );
    $(".ui.modal.child")
      .modal({
        onShow: function () {
          alert("child");
        }
      })
      .modal("attach events", ".ui.modal.parent .approve", "show");
    $(".ui.modal.parent").modal("show");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**First:** unfortunately the documentation is not showing all relevant code in this example. Property `allowMultiple: true` needs to be applied both to the parent and child modals. So either you add a class called `coupled` to those elements like in the documentation, or just refer to both on this line:

```js
$(".modal.parent, .modal.child").modal({ allowMultiple: true });
```

**Second:** in your code the "Open Child" button is also an `.approve` button, so it closes down the parent modal while you want to keep it open. Instead of using that button, I'd suggest to create a new one with class `open-child` as you can see below.

```
.ui.modal.parent
  i.close.icon
  .header Parent Modal
  .content Multiple modals allowed
  .actions
    .ui.approve.button OK
    .ui.deny.button Cancel
    .ui.open-child.button Open Child
```

and then open child modal when that button is clicked:

```js
$(".ui.modal.child").modal("attach events", ".parent.modal .open-child.button");
```

Codepen with these changes can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/derloopkat/pen/wvdggzX).